# How to define two aliases for one command in one statement

Tags: macos, bash, unix, alias

I know how to configure aliases in bash, but is there a way to map an alias for with two possible shortcuts in one statement?

Here is the two line version

```
alias "gac"="git add . && git commit -am "
alias "gitac"="git add . && git commit -am "
```

I imagine the solution, if possible, would look something like this:

Pseudo Code: `alias "alias1 || alias2"="command"`

Is this even possible with aliases or do I have to use a function and if so how?

Comment: `bash: alias: \`git ac': invalid alias name`

Comment: ...But to answer the question: `for a in gac gitac ; do alias "$a"="..." ; done`

Comment: Am I correct in assuming semi-colons are the line endings here

Comment: No: Semicolons are semicolons. But they could be *replaced with* line endings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ alias {gac,gitac}="git add . && git commit -am "
$ alias gac
alias gac='git add . && git commit -am '
$ alias gitac
alias gitac='git add . && git commit -am '
```

Comment: Curious how you knew to use the braces. Can't find this in the documentation anywhere. Care to share where you found this or how you knew to do this?

Comment: @trebek1, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
alias "gac"="git add . && git commit -am " "gitac"="gac"
```

Comment: Isn't this just two statements put into one line?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre, Nope. Try putting a  `;` where you think it's being two statements. You will find that it won't work. and also `alias` command is used only once, not twice.